# What exactly does the task Mocha Test Parser

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, bamboo

Can someone show me how the output from Atlassian Bamboo "Mocha Test Parser" looks like? I run successfully the task "Mocha Test Runer" and get a mocha.json as result. But don't see any diagrams or something else.

Comment: Can you post an image containing what you get ? I haven't use mocha with bamboo but I've seen test results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Mocha Test Parser" task will read your test results from *mocha.json* file, that has to be generated by "Mocha Test Runer" task and display them in Tests tab in the Bamboo, and next to the each build.